No QtMultimedia backends found. Only QMediaDevices, QAudioDevice, QSoundEffect, QAudioSink, and QAudioSource are available
I am working on a project on Asahi Linux on Macbook air m1 and tried Camera class in qml file.
Tried to load qml in pyside 6 using qqmlapplicationengine
.........
CaptureSession {
            camera: Camera {
                id: camera

                focusMode: Camera.FocusModeAutoNear
                customFocusPoint: Qt.point(0.2, 0.2) // Focus relative to top-left corner
            }
            videoOutput: videoOutput
        }

        VideoOutput {
            id: videoOutput
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
.......

It shows the following error:
No QtMultimedia backends found. Only QMediaDevices, QAudioDevice, QSoundEffect, QAudioSink, and QAudioSource are available.
Failed to initialize QMediaCaptureSession "Not available"
Failed to initialize QCamera "Not available"
Failed to create QVideoSink "Not available"

By I've seen similar posts talking about the same issue but not in asahi linux. From those articles I tried to downgrade pyside6 to a lower version(6.7.0 from 6.8) but it didn't work.

Downgrading to 6.7.0 will probably change nothing, as the 6.7.* tree is known to have introduced changes in many unrelated modules that resulted in lots of bugs. 6.8 should be fine (but you should probably wait for 6.8.1 at least). Also consider changing the backend.

If this is the build provided by the distro, they may have not built the backend. Use the QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS variable to get more info.
In that case, you may want to build qtmultimedia by yourself, or build Qt entirely. Make sure that ffmpeg libs are found during the configuration of the qtmultimedia module. It may not provide a hardware decoder/encoder, but you may get the software implementation.
Note that I do not own that system, so I cannot try.
